# UITableViewCell not filling width of table

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

My table cell is not filling the width of my table. Code below:

Controller with table view:

```
import UIKit

class MenuController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var menuTable:UITableView!

    var rootNav:UINavigationController!

    private var cellIdentifier = "MenuCell"

    //This is an array of arrays of dictionaries with String key and Any value
    //Top level array is sections
    //Second level array is items
    //Dictionary holds data for that individual cell
    private final var menuItems:[[[String:Any?]]] = [

        //Section 1
        [
            //Shot Chart
            ["image":Images.BALL,"title":" Chart","stack":ViewStacks.CHART],

            //Profile
            ["image":Images.PROFILE,"title":"Profile","stack":ViewStacks.PROFILE]
        ],

        //Section 2
        [
            //Logout
            ["image":Images.LOGOUT,"title":"Logout","stack":nil]
        ]

    ]

    init(rootNav:UINavigationController, nibName:String?, bundle:Bundle?) {
        self.rootNav = rootNav
        super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Table View Datasource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:MenuCell? = menuTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! MenuCell?
        if cell == nil {
            cell = MenuCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }
        let cellProperties = menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell!.imageView?.image = (cellProperties["image"] as! UIImage)
        cell!.titleLbl?.text = (cellProperties["title"] as! String)
        return cell!
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems[section].count
    }

    //Table View Delegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

}
```

UITableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class MenuCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var iconImg:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLbl:UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        super.setSelected(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Constraints on cell:
[image]

What cells should look like:
[image]

The image shows, but no text, no background, nothing. It's as if the autoLayout is doing nothing and the image is just showing in it's default size.

Comment: @Joe Your answer addresses only height, which in this case should always be 50. I assumed the 'heightForRowAt' would address that. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Try to did select method. see you can print some data from your array.if your array not nil...

Comment: @Joe The array is not nil, if you're referring to the array of cells. Otherwise, the images would not show. If you look at the code above, menuItems contains the array used to build the cells, and is not nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have made a xib of `UITableViewCell` and have not registered that.

It is showing image because you are using `cell.imageView` which is the default imageView for `UITableViewCell` and it always satisfy the nil condition. You haven't provided any outlet of your imageView which you have drag and dropped into your `UITableViewCell` xib.

So change your `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    menuTable.register(UINib(nibName: "MenuCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")
}
```

Make sure the identifier you have given of your `UITableViewCell` subclass i.e. `MenuCell` is **MenuCell**

Also change your `cellForRow` method to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! MenuCell
    let cellProperties = menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    // you are using imageView which is the default property for UITableViewCell. Create your own imageView outlet. Name it as menuImageView and replace imageView with menuImageView
    cell.imageView?.image = (cellProperties["image"] as! UIImage)

    cell.titleLbl?.text = (cellProperties["title"] as! String)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rajan mentioned in his answer issue is not with your layout. So just put this function in your customTableViewCell class

```
    class func cellForTableView(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> MenuCell TableViewCell {
    let k MenuCell TableViewCellIdentifier = "kMenuCellTableViewCellIdentifier"
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MenuCellTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: kMenuCellTableViewCellIdentifier)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kMenuCellTableViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuCellTableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` use this as

```
let cell = MenuCellTableViewCell.cellForTableView(tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() // Do something with your cell
```